# automatically update .edmx file?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I am not sure if there is a way to update edmx file automatically when database is changed.

If not, is there a method like UpdateModelFromDatabase I can use when I insert something into the database.

If not either, how to handle this situation by using edmx: a user reset his password and need log in again with his new password?

thanks

Comment: ......then why people use edmx?

Comment: Do you want to update schema or data?

Comment: When a user reset his password, the new password goes into the database  I think. so should update data? (not sure)

Comment: http://www.asp.net/get-started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I just understood your question. Just so things are clear: `UpdateModelFromDatabase` updates the structure of your DB into your EDMX schema. This has nothing to do with the DATA that is in the tables.

If you want to update the data, then it depends wether you use a [repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175/repository-pattern-tutorial-in-c-sharp) or not. I assume you don't. So to update your context (which updates your data), juste recreate it before every query!

Example:

```
Connected listOfConnecteds                
using (var context = AccesData.GetNewContext())
{
     connected = context.Connected
                       .FirstOrDefault(c => c.IsActive)
                       .ToList();
     if (connected != null)
     {
         connected.IsActive = false;
         context.SaveChanges();
     }
}
```

EDIT: It's `context.SaveChanges();`, my bad

Comment: why need a repository? what is the advantage to use that?

Comment: Repositories let you use only one context per entiry throughout your application. But if you're just beginning with .net, I suggest you wait a little before digging into the repository patterns. I'll update my answer with a way to update data.